# Boost converter as power supply for H-bridge

Tags: h-bridge, boost

I am looking for a way to be able to power the H-brirdge from a boost converter.

I have a voltage source of 13V to 15V and would like to boost that up to around 17V (accuracy isnt that important) at around 4A, to power **only the H-bridge**.

I currently have the following circuit (please note that there are MOSFET dirvers missing):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flsNoS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I simulate the following circuit in LTspice I get the following waveforms:

[image: output]

Green line represents the voltage coming from the boost converter and the blue line represents the current through R1.

[image: output]

Here, blue line represents the current through R1, while red (M2, M5) and light blue (M3, M4) lines represent H-bridge switching.  There is 1\$\mu s\$ dead-time between H-bridge switching.

Can someone please explaing what is going on? And what do I need to do to make this work as intended?

**edit:**

If I get rid of the H-bridge and connect R1 directly to the output of the boost converter I get the deisred result (but I need H-bridge).

R1 represents a speaker.

Comment: How did you intend it to work?

Comment: @Andyaka Get a flat ~17V across R1 at all times.

Comment: But the H bridge is driven at 10kHz so that cannot happen.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes I meant with minimum '0V times'. But anyway I get these weird triangle like waveforms from the boost converter and in the current through R1.

Comment: I haven't looked at it in detail, but looks like your boost converter's effective output impedance is too low.  Most boost converters use negative feedback to lower the output impedance and keep the output constant.  You might try that instead of an open-loop approach.

Comment: @JohnD How would I add a negative feedback? V2, V3, V4 are all coming from a single microcontroller.

Comment: You could just use a boost converter IC instead of running it from a micro controller.  If you have enough bandwidth in the micro controller and enough speed in your A/D you could try a digital control loop.

Comment: @JohnD Do I understand you correctly, I would monitor boost converter output voltage and when the voltage would drop I would increase V2 duty cycle? And vice-versa.

Comment: That's the general idea, but there's some control theory involved to make sure the loop is stable. If you don't understand digital controls and loop compensation you're better off just using a boost converter IC.

Comment: @JohnD If the frequency of V2 is 250kHz (or maybe 100kHz) what will be the minimum AD sampling frequency to correctly compensate for errors (I can go as high as 40kHz) ?

Comment: 40kHz is sufficient, but you'll need a digital compensator.  Boost converters have a right half plane zero to watch for, and digital control has transport lag, but you might be able to get your loop closed at 3-4kHz if your micro is capable of the compensation calculations between A/D samples. It's not trivial to get a good response unless you're familiar with DSP and control theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that all your mosfets are N-channel.

It would be easier to use P-channel mosfets for M2 and M3, since the Vgs is more stable than for NMOS.

[image]

---

I think the behavior you're seeing in the waveforms is because Vgs is varying with the current through R1.

From http://www.learn-c.com/experiment7.htm:

[image]

> There is a bit of a problem when a MOSFET is used for Switch A or
>   Switch B. The Drain is connected to the V+ for the motor and the
>   Source to the motor. If the gate is then made to be 2 volts greater
>   than the Source, the MOSFET will turn on. When that happens however,
>   the voltage at the Source will increase until the gate is no longer 2
>   volts greater than the Source and the MOSFET will turn off. Another
>   voltage source is needed that is always greater than Motor V+ by at
>   least 2 volts.

Comment: Actually 2V is the threshold for this part, in order to get effective enhancement you need MORE than 2V.  It's 29mOhms at 2.8V and 13.5mOhms at 4.5V.

Comment: This helped maybe a bit, the issue still persists. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This schematic is fundamentally wrong. Mosfet driver needs to drive gates in relation to mosfet source pin not system ground. In reality this is achieved by virtual floating ground in mosfet driver chips. Alternatively you could use 4 opto isolators but this on it own could cause problems with inadequate raise/fall times.